# VPN Connection (Fritzbox) works for Android Client but not for Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, android

I use a Fritzbox 7530 Router in my home network as a VPN server. The VPN is configured as "IPSec Xauth PSK" with following settings: server name, IPSecID, IPSec shared key, user name and password.
The connection works just fine using an Android Device with a preinstalled VPN client but I cannot do the same using Windows 10 Pro or Ubuntu 20. In both configurations the connection cannot be established at all.

**Android phone settings (VPN works just fine):**

[image]

**Windows 10 Pro settings:**

[image]

**Ubuntu 20 settings:**

[image]

[image]

I guess if it works fine with Android it has to work with any system which fulfils the requirments.
Do you have an experience with such problems?

Comment: Any log messages on the vpn server side, or the client side that might help us narrow it down?

Comment: fritzbox is not a business environment. Therefore it is off topic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com

Comment: I don't really think the problem is specific for the Fritzbox. I guess it's just some setting in the client which is done in android devices by default and has to be set in Windows/Ubuntu explicitly.

Comment: Cross-posted to Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1735741/356789